# Prevent Sequelize logger from including database credentials

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, bunyan

I noticed in Sequelize version `4.4.2` that the log information includes database credentials when creating the model.

This is problematic if you wish to use the logs of query information in a production environment to audit queries or debug errors. Here is my sequelize setup:

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';
import { log } from './plugins';

const createConnection = () => new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    process.env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    {
        host: process.env.SERVER_POSTGRES_HOST,
        port: process.env.SERVER_POSTGRES_PORT,
        dialect: 'postgres',
        logging: log.trace.bind(log)
});

const connection = createConnection();
```

EDIT:

It appear to be directly related to attaching a custom logger the way that I am doing it. It's passing a config object to the logger which includes the sequelize configuration which also includes database credentials. Relying on the console.log doesn't cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The logging configuration should be

```
logging: (msg) => logger.trace(msg)
```

This will only pass the msg information and not the Sequelize configuration.
See [Issue 7821](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/7821)